# Storing a converted image in a variable and display it in my webpage

Tags: php

I have a function in my class file that converts an image to grayscale. What I need is a way to store that converted image in a variable so it can be displayed on my page with rest if the users info instead of just a white page with the converted image. I would appreciate any suggestions.
here is the code:

```
function GoBlackWhite($pic){
    $file = "pictures/$pic";
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    $imgw = imagesx($im);
    $imgh = imagesy($im);
    for ($i=0; $i<$imgw; $i++){
        for ($j=0; $j<$imgh; $j++){
        // get the rgb value for current pixel
        $rgb = @imagecolorat($im, $i, $j);
        // extract each value for r, g, b
        $rr = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $gg = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $bb = $rgb & 0xFF;
        // get the Value from the RGB value
        $g = round(($rr + $gg + $bb) / 3);
        // grayscale values have r=g=b=g
        $val = imagecolorallocate($im, $g, $g, $g);
        // set the gray value
        imagesetpixel ($im, $i, $j, $val);
        }
    }
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($im);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send *either* a html page, *or* an image, but not both at once. Thats a "limitation" of the http-protocol. If you want to include an image in your website, use the `<img>`-element

```
<img src="/path/to/image.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you need either two scripts (one for the HTML and one for the Image data) or one script that changes its behavior based on a query parameter. For example (this is a script that changes based on a query parameter):

```
<?php
if( isset($_REQUEST['pic']) )
{
    // Call your function and return bytes with content type header as above
    exit;
}
?>
<html>
<body>
The converted image:<br/>
<img src='<?php echo $PHP_SELF . "?pic=myimagefile.jpg";?>'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a php page which streams back the image's bytes, setting the MIME type as you did in your example.  Then `<img src="/path/to/image.php" />`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, see if the [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) fits your scenarios. This will only be applicable, if you have very small images, and if you're not likely to serve them more than once.